# What does it mean to follow the person into the referee's notebook?

Tags: football, terminology

What does it mean to be *in the referee's notebook* first, and why would someone else *follow them into the referee's notebook* after that?

Answer (score 3):

The referee makes records important information about the match in a notebook to act as the official record of the match. This includes goals, but in this context also cautions - a player receiving a caution can be (unofficially) described as "going into the referee's notebook", and a second player receiving a caution can be described as "following the first player into the referee's notebook".

In case it's not obvious, this is also the derivation of a caution being described as a "booking".

Comment: A possible context could be a player being booked, her teammate arguing with the referee and the teammate being booked for dissent. That fits the question well as the two players would get a yellow card in a short time and
 following from a single incident.